# How to transform SQL query into JPQL query?

Tags: sql, jpql

I'm looking for how to transform the following query (SQL) into query JPQL;

```
SELECT * FROM equipements eq
LEFT JOIN check_lists checks
ON eq.id_equipements = checks.equipements_id 
LEFT JOIN responses_check_lists resp 
ON checks.id_check_lists = resp.check_lists_id
AND resp.missions_id = 15 
AND eq.id_equipements = 1 
ORDER BY checks.id_check_lists
```

I followed the documents on the internet but I do not get the correct transformation of my query in JPQL.

I know that the attributes of the query will be replaced by the attributes of the class.

I posted here to help me in transforming the SQL query.

**Edit1:**

```
@Query(
            "SELECT  r, checks, eq"
            + " FROM Equipements eq"
            + " LEFT JOIN CheckLists checks "
            + " ON eq.idEquipements = checks.equipements.idEquipements"
            + " LEFT JOIN ResponsesCheckLists r"
            + " ON checks.idCheckLists = r.CheckLts.idCheckLists"
            + " AND r.Respmission.idMission= :idmiss "
            + " AND eq.idEquipements= :idEqp"
            + " ORDER BY checks.idCheckLists ASC"
        )
```

**Error of Edit1:**

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode   +-[IDENT] IdentNode:
>   'r' {originalText=r}
>
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidPathException: Invalid path:
>   'checks.idCheckLists'

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Please, how to make the transformation from SQL to JPQL?

Comment: Can you show the code of your mapped entities Equipements, ResponsesCheckLists, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analysing your SQL and without see the entities, your JPQL can be something like this:

```
SELECT eq FROM Equipements eq
LEFT JOIN eq.checks check
LEFT JOIN check.responses resp 
LEFT JOIN resp.missions mission WITH mission.id = :idmiss
WHERE eq.id = :idEqp
ORDER BY check.id
```

But, to be something like this, you need to adjust the mapping of your entities (entity name, column names, etc).